# cross domain tracking in google tag manager under two different GTM container

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a question regarding cross domain tracking via GTM.

Let's say I have two website: abc.com (main site), def.com (transaction site), customer go to abc.com, click "buy now" then is directed to def.com to complete the transaction, and the thank you page is back to abc.com. There are two respective GTM container for abc.com and def.com

In this case, the cross domain tracking should be set via GTM abc.com container or def.com container or both?

Answer (score 1):

Cross-domain tracking should be set via both containers, but using the same tracker ID (UA-XXXXX). Because the first domain needs to decorate links with `ClientID` parameter from GA cookie file, the second domain needs to accept this parameter - it is not default setting.

Create a new GA tracking ID (it's better, let's each site has their own GA trackers and one common GA tracker for cross-domain linking only). 
Then add new GA tracker via GTM on first site. Settings see on screenshot:
[image]
[image]

Then add the same GA tracker via GTM on second site and configure it in the same way.

See GA Support to know how to set up view, filter and so on.
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en

Comment: Your answer is interesting, could you develop it a bit more, please?